# Getting Memory error to perform operation with readline python

Tags: python

I am reading the file using readlines() function in python and storing the data to variable. it is worked fine with small text file, but getting the "Memory error" for big sized file.

Is there something we can use instead of readline() and store the data to varibale ass list?

```
with open("some_test.txt") as fp:
    line= fp.readlines()

Where Line is the List
```

Comment: You can just iterate the file object directly rather than load the whole file into memory

Comment: Note that you keep changing  between `readline` and `readlines`. Both exist and they do different things

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over lines

Try this way:

```
with open("some_test.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        do_your_stuff(line)
        ...
```

EDITED: I made a mistake (didn't iterate)

Answer (score 0):

yeild is one of the best approach to handle huge data. Following link will helpful for you

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python
```